# How to add a folder and its content to the standard paths of Playframework and Heroku?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, lucene

I have a Scala Play framework 2.7.x application which I deploy in Heroku. I use Lucene to index the WebApp and since there is no `JdbcDirectory` in Lucene I need to use their `FSDirectory` instead and that leads to issues with Heroku because I can't generate the index files under `$APP_HOME/lucene-index/*` in Heroku otherwise it will be wiped out each time. This leads me to two possible solutions and this is the simpler one:

1. Generate the `$APP_HOME/lucene-index` locally before deployment and save it in GIT, this folder will be at the same level as `$APP_HOME/app` and `$APP_HOME/public`.
2. Integrate the new nonstandard Play folder `$APP_HOME/lucene-index` so that it gets copied by Heroku (the purpose of this OP).
3. Upon startup the application checks for this folder and if doesn't exist (local case) gets generated otherwise it opens it (Heroku case).

Do I need to do something special on #2 to have Heroku recognize `$APP_HOME/lucene-index/` as a folder that needs to be packaged together with the application? e.g. I would not like to put the  `$APP_HOME/lucene-index/` under `$APP_HOME/conf/` for this to work.

Here I find the [Anatomy of a Play 2.7.x application](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Anatomy) but there is no word on how to add extra path folders to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I was after was to include the `./lucene-index` folder as part of the Play dist. This is accomplished by changing the `build.sbt` file adding:

```
//********************************************************
// Add lucene-index to the dist
//********************************************************

import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "lucene-index")
```

Now it deploys to Heroku and it all works nicely.